# Objetivo do str()

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Queria saber qual função é desempenhada pela função `str()` na linha 33(o código não funciona sem essa função, dá esse erro: TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.**format**)

````
jogadores = dict()
pontos = list()
while True:
    jogadores['Nome'] = str(input('Nome do jogador: '))
    quant_parti = int(input(f'Quantas partidas {jogadores["Nome"]} jogou? '))
    for c in range(0, quant_parti):
        pontos.append(int(input(f'  => Na {c}° partida, quantos gols {jogadores["Nome"]} fez? ')))
    jogadores['Gols'] = pontos[:]
    jogadores['Total'] = sum(pontos)
    pontos.clear()
    time.append(jogadores.copy())
    jogadores.clear()
    while True:
        opcao = str(input('Deseja continuar? [S / N] ')).upper()
        if opcao in 'SN':
            break
        else:
            print(f'\033[1;31m[ ERROR ]\033[m Tente somente S ou N.')
    if opcao == 'S':
        print('-=-=-='*10)
    if opcao == 'N':
        print('-=-=-='*10)
        break
print('Cód', end=' ')
for k in time[0].keys():
    print(f'{k:>12}', end='')
print()
print('-=-=-='*10)
for i, v in enumerate(time):
    print(f'{i}', end=' ')
    for value in v.values():
        print(f'{str(value):>12}', end=' ')
    print()
print('<<< FIM >>>')```
````

Comment: A resposta abaixo explicou para que serve o `str`, mas para entender **porque** `f'{value:>12}'` não funciona em todos os casos (como aconteceu no seu código, quando `value` é uma lista), veja [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/448955/112052). E só para constar, outra alternativa é usar `f'{value!s:>12}'`, pois `value!s` é equivalente a chamar `str(value)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `str` tem como objeto transformar o parâmetro recebido em uma string.

Logo se a função receber o número `1` como parâmetro, terá como retorno a string `'1'`, mas ela não limita-se a trabalhar com números.

---

Veja esse exemplo:

```
numero = 10

print(type(numero)) #Aqui será um número (int)

print(type(str(numero))) #Utilizando a função str, torna-se uma string (str)

boolean = True

print(type(boolean)) #Aqui será um boolean (bool)

print(type(str(boolean))) #Utilizando a função str, torna-se uma string (str)
```

A função `str` utilizada da forma acima, transformou tanto o número inteiro quando um valor booleano em string.

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/BreakableUntriedDeclaration

---

No seu exemplo, ocorre um erro pois você está utilizando uma formatação de strings na impressão:

```
print(f'{str(value):>12}', end=' ')
```

Por isso é necessário a utilização da função `str`, caso queira fazer um teste, remova a função `str` e também a formatação, verá que não vai mais gerar o erro citado, mas também é claro, a string deixará de ser formatada:

```
print(f'{value}', end=' ')
```

---

Documentação: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str

Comment: Quando vi a pergunta fiquei intrigado em entender porque `f'{value:>12}'` não funciona quando `value` é uma lista (já que com números, por exemplo, funciona - eu achei que o `value` sempre era transformado em string antes de aplicar a formatação, mas com listas dá erro e só funciona se usar explicitamente `str`). Isso acabou gerando [esta pergunta](/q/448955/112052) - que é um ótimo complemento, pois vc só diz que o erro ocorre por causa da formatação de strings, mas não é bem isso (ou não é **só** isso) - enfim, no link tem mais detalhes :-)