# Por que as opções de formatação não funcionam com listas, dicionários e outros objetos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, característica-linguagem, python-internals, cpython

Quando quero imprimir um número ou uma string, posso usar [*f-strings*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) (em Python >= 3.6) ou [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), e posso passar somente a variável entre chaves, ou usar as [opções de formatação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec). Ex:

```
numero, texto = 10, 'abc'

# passando somente as variáveis
print(f'{numero} {texto}')
# ou
#print('{} {}'.format(numero, texto))

# usando as opções de formatação
# número alinhado à esquerda, ocupando 6 posições, texto alinhado à direita ocupando 10 posições
print(f'{numero:<6} {texto:>10}')
# ou
#print('{:<6} {:>12}'.format(numero, texto))
```

Saída:

```
10 abc
10            abc
```

Mas se faço o mesmo com listas ou dicionários, apenas a primeira opção funciona:

```
lista = [1, 2]
dic = {'a': 1}
print(f'{lista} {dic}')
# ou
#print('{} {}'.format(lista, dic))

print(f'{lista:<10} {dic:>15}')
# ou
#print('{:<10} {:>15}'.format(lista, dic))
```

O primeiro `print` imprime:

```
[1, 2] {'a': 1}
```

Mas o segundo `print` (com as opções de formatação `<10` e `>15`) dá erro:

> ```
> TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.__format__
> ```

---

Se eu tentar a mesma coisa com uma instância de uma classe qualquer que eu criei, também ocorre a mesma coisa. Ex:

```
class Teste:
    def __init__(self, valor):
        self.valor = valor

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Teste({self.valor})'

t = Teste(42)
print(f't={t}')
print(f'{t:>10}')
```

O primeiro `print` imprime:

```
t=Teste(42)
```

Já o segundo `print` dá erro:

> ```
> TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Teste.__format__
> ```

---

Minha pergunta **não** é sobre como corrigir (*bastaria transformar a lista/dicionário/objeto em string - por exemplo, usando [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) - ou iterar pelos seus elementos/atributos e ir montando a string manualmente, etc*).

O que eu quero saber é por qual motivo isso acontece. Por que não é possível usar as opções de formatação com listas, dicionários e instâncias de classes quaisquer, enquanto que se passá-los sem nenhuma opção funciona normalmente? Existe algum detalhe no funcionamento interno desses tipos que os difere de números e strings, quando estes são formatados?

Comment: Antes que alguém estranhe que eu mesmo respondi minha própria pergunta, isso é [**perfeitamente aceitável e dentro das regras**](/help/self-answer). Inclusive, a [página de fazer pergunta](/questions/ask) tem uma [opção para postar a própria resposta juntamente com a pergunta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPEQw.png). Claro que se alguém tiver uma resposta melhor e mais completa, com certeza deve postá-la. O objetivo é trazer este conhecimento para o site (pois fiz uma busca e não tinha encontrado nada a respeito).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando você passa somente a variável sem nenhuma opção de formatação (`print(f'{variavel}')`), internamente está sendo chamado o método `__str__` da mesma. Ou seja, no caso da classe `Teste`, como ela já tinha este método implementado:

```
class Teste:
    def __init__(self, valor):
        self.valor = valor

    def __str__(self):
        print('chamando __str__') # incluindo um print só para mostrar que realmente passa por aqui
        return f'Teste({self.valor})'

t = Teste(42)
print(f'{t}')
```

A saída será:

```
chamando __str__
Teste(42)
```

Mas **na verdade** o que está sendo chamado de fato é o método `__format__`, que [segundo a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__), é chamado ao avaliar o objeto quando este está em uma [*f-string*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings), ou ao passá-lo para [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) ou ainda ao passá-lo para o *built-in* [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format).

Mas como a classe `Teste` não definiu o método `__format__`, então ela usa o que foi herdado de `object`. E se verificarmos a implementação do mesmo (no [código fonte do CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c) - versão consultada em 28/04/2020, com comentários removidos):

```c
static PyObject *
object___format___impl(PyObject *self, PyObject *format_spec)
{
    if (PyUnicode_GET_LENGTH(format_spec) > 0) {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                     "unsupported format string passed to %.200s.__format__",
                     Py_TYPE(self)->tp_name);
        return NULL;
    }
    return PyObject_Str(self);
}
```

Ou seja, quando não é passada nenhuma opção de formatação (apenas `{variavel}`), ele não entra no `if` e retorna `PyObject_Str(self)` (e [segundo a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_Str), `PyObject_Str(algo)` é equivalente a chamar `str(algo)` - que por sua vez, [chama `algo.__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__)).

Agora se eu passar alguma opção de formatação (como por exemplo `print(f'{variavel:>10}')`), ele entra no `if` e mostra a mensagem de erro ("*unsupported format string etc*").

> *Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__), este comportamento de lançar o `TypeError` caso a string de formatação não seja vazia [vale desde o Python 3.4](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/2cd8ce469021e851f4ab70106d696136ecddcd51#diff-c3cf251f16d5a03a9e7d4639f2d6f998), e a chamada para `str(self)` vale desde o Python 3.7 (antes era chamado `format(str(self), '')`, conforme consta [neste commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/7e19dbc92ec06a987eaae72f7cdfd32006aa4960)).*

Ou seja, para isso funcionar na minha classe, eu teria que implementar o método `__format__`:

```
class Teste:
    def __init__(self, valor):
        self.valor = valor

    def __str__(self):
        print('chamando __str__')
        return f'Teste({self.valor})'

    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        print(f'chamando __format__ com formato: "{format_spec}"')
        return f'{self.valor:{format_spec}}'

t = Teste(42)
print(f'{t}')
print(f'{t:>10}')
```

Agora sim ambos os `print`'s funcionam (e eu implementei o método `__format__` de forma a não delegar para `__str__`, mas poderia tê-lo feito se quisesse). A saída é:

```
chamando __format__ com formato: ""
42
chamando __format__ com formato: ">10"
        42
```

E a mesma saída seria obtida se eu fizesse:

```
print('{}'.format(t))
print('{:>10}'.format(t))
```

---

Enfim, é por isso que as opções de formatação não funcionam com listas e dicionários, pois as respectivas classes ([`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) e [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict)) não implementam o método `__format__` e usam a implementação herdada de `object` (que delega para `str` quando nenhuma opção é passada, e dá erro quando as opções são usadas - por isso funciona quando faço somente `print(f'{lista}')`).

Infelizmente não dá para implementar `__format__` em listas e dicionários, já que [não é possível adicionar métodos novos nas classes nativas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21320086), então o jeito é transformá-las em strings mesmo (seja usando `str`, seja iterando pelos seus elementos e montando a string no formato desejado).

Já números e strings implementam o método `__format__` e por isso funcionam com as opções de formatação.

E como já dito, isso não se limita à *f-strings*. O mesmo comportamento ocorre com `str.format` e o *built-in* `format`:

```
t = Teste(42) # usando a última versão acima, com a classe Teste implementando __format__
# ambas as linhas abaixo chamam Teste.__format__
print('{:>10}'.format(t))
print(format(t, '>10'))

lista = [1, 2]
# ambas as linhas abaixo lançam TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.__format__
print('{:>10}'.format(lista))
print(format(lista, '>10'))
```

---

Aliás, é por isso que também é possível formatar as classes do [módulo `datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) desta maneira - como por exemplo `f'{datetime.now():%d/%m/%Y}'` - pois essas classes sobrescrevem o método `__format__`, delegando a chamada para `strftime`. Sendo assim, eu também poderia fazer algo similar com a classe `Teste`, e definir os formatos que eu quiser:

```
class Teste:
    # ... construtor, etc

    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        formatos = { # formatos customizados
          'formato_x' : f'formato x -> {self.valor}',
          'outro formato' : f'outro: {self.valor}'
        }
        if format_spec in formatos:
            return formatos[format_spec]

        return f'{self.valor:{format_spec}}'

t = Teste(42)
print(f'{t:formato_x}') # formato x -> 42
print(f'{t:outro formato}') # outro: 42
print(f'{t:>10}')

# ou
#print('{:formato_x}'.format(t))
#print('{:outro formato}'.format(t))
#print('{:>10}'.format(t))
```

Saída:

```
formato x -> 42
outro: 42
        42
```

Comment: como no C# que você sempre tem o `ToString()` e as pessoas acham que é um conversor para texto, o que não é bem verdade, mas se quiser algo mais específico cheio de graça deve usar o `IFormattable` que fornece um provedor de formatação e é o que muitas vezes a pessoa quer no lugar do `ToString()` puro. Falo disso em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/212797/101