# Python: print(...{}' .format) ou print(...+str(...))

Tags: python

## codigo versao 1

tempF = input('Temperatura em graus Farenheit: ')

tempC = (5 * (int(tempF) - 32) / 9)

print('Temperatura em graus Celsius: ' + str(tempC))

**No código acima (#1), para exibir a mensagem final, tenho de converter a variável tempC para string e o código funciona como esperado.**

---

## codigo versao 2

tempF = input('Temperatura em graus Farenheit: ')

tempC = (5 * (int(tempF) - 32) / 9)

print('Temperatura em graus Celsius: {}' .format(tempC))

**No código acima (#2), para exibir a mensagem final, uso o .format sem converter a variável tempC para string e o código funciona como esperado.**

Quais as razões para ambos os códigos funcionarem? Algum apontamento relacionado à performance? Versão do Python? Comandos obsoletos? Qual versão de código é recomendável?

Comment: Não sei se chega a ser duplicada, mas tem uma explicação [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/448955/112052). Basicamente, `format` acaba chamando `str` "por baixo dos panos"

Answer (score 0):

No primeiro caso, vc tem que converter pois o tempC está como int, e no caso, vc está somando strings, caso contrário ficaria uma string + int.

No segundo caso vc está formatando o tempC para dentro de uma string, o que na prática da no mesmo que:

```
print("Temperatura em graus Celsius: ", tempC)
```

ou ate mesmo:

```
print("Temperatura em graus Celsius: ", end='')
print(tempC)
```

Por fim, recomendo a vc usar a formatação do tipo:

```
print(f"Temperatura em graus Celsius:{tempC}")
```

Comment: Me esqueci que a tempC poderia ser um float tbm, mas ficaria quase que a mesma explicação

Answer (score 0):

No primeiro caso, são realizadas as seguintes operações. 1º Captura um valor no tipo "string". 2º Converte o valor capturado para "inteiro", inseri-o na fórmula, realiza o cálculo e armazena o resultado na variável "tempC" convertido em "float" (conversão implícita. Pois toda operação de divisão "/", produz um valor float). 3º Converte o valor da variável armazenada em "tempC" para "string" e, em seguida, a exibe.

No segundo caso, são realizadas as seguintes operações. 1º Captura um valor no tipo "string". 2º Converte o valor capturado para "inteiro", inseri-o na fórmula, realiza o cálculo e armazena o resultado na variável "tempC" convertido em "float" (conversão implícita, como já falei). 3º Chama a função "format" (embora, não esteja passando os parâmetros de formatação) para exibir o valor da variável armazenada em "tempC".

No primeiro caso, você está utilizando duas vezes (em separado) a função "str()".
No segundo caso, você está utilizando apenas uma vez a função "str()".

A conversão de uma variável para string demanda de mais recursos computacionais. Quando você chama esta função duas ou mais vezes em um algoritmo, você o deixa menos eficiente.

Para programas de pequenas quantidades de variáveis, o desempenho não será alterado substancialmente, porém para programas que necessite manipular grandes números de variáveis, o desempenho será afetado bruscamente.

Outra coisa, em Python 3, mais precisamente a partir da versão 3.6, podemos exibir o resultado de saída de diversas forma. Utilizando o seu código com algumas modificações que julgo pertinentes, podemos exibi a saída (output) de várias formas

Exemplo 1º

```
tempF = int(input('Temperatura em graus Farenheit: '))

tempC = (((5 * tempF) - 32) / 9)
print('Temperatura em graus Celsius: '.format(tempC))
```

Exemplo 2º

```
tempF = int(input('Temperatura em graus Farenheit: '))

tempC = (((5 * tempF) - 32) / 9)
print(f'Temperatura em graus Celsius: {tempC}')
```

Neste caso utilizamos as "f-Strings", que nada mais é do que um formato suportado por interpretadores Python de versões iguais ou superiores a 3.6.

Exemplo 3º

```
tempF = int(input('Temperatura em graus Farenheit: '))

tempC = (((5 * tempF) - 32) / 9)
print(temC)
```

Esta é outra forma de exibir a resposta sem muito enfeite.

Exemplo 4º:

```
from sys import stdout

tempF = int(input('Temperatura em graus Farenheit: '))

tempC = str(((5 * tempF) - 32) / 9)
stdout.write(tempC)
```

Exemplo 5º:

```
tempF = int(input('Temperatura em graus Farenheit: '))

tempC = ((5 * tempF - 32) / 9)
print(f'Temperatura em graus C°: {tempC:.2f}')
```

Neste caso estamos formatando o valor de saída com duas casas decimais