# Como "clonar" uma InputStream?

Tags: java, io, clone, inputstream

Frequentemente preciso ler uma  `InputStream` mais do que uma vez. Por exemplo, para repassar o conteúdo da *stream* para múltiplos métodos.

```
void readStream(InputStream input) throws Exception {
    var result1 = doSomething(input);
    var result2 = doSomethingElse(input);
    // Faz algo com os resultados
}
```

As chamadas *downstream* não estão sob meu controle. Elas consomem e fecham `input`, de forma que não posso simplesmente marcar e resetar a *stream* original.

Abrir uma nova `InputStream` também não é conveniente no meu caso. `input` está ligada a uma fonte lenta e limitada.

Gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira de "clonar" `input` de forma que eu possa passar *streams* diferentes para os métodos *downstream*?

Ou seja, queria fazer algo como no código abaixo (que não funciona):

```
void readStream(InputStream input) throws Exception {
    var clonedInput = ((InputStream) input.clone());
    var result1 = doSomething(input);
    var result2 = doSomethingElse(clonedInput);
    // Faz algo com os resultados
}
```

É possível fazer algo assim? Caso não seja, quais são as melhores alternativas?

---

**Atribuição:** Adaptado da pergunta [*How to Clone an InputStream?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5923817/664577) perguntada pelo usuário [Renato Dinhani](https://stackexchange.com/users/380750/renato-dinhani?tab=accounts) no [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: +1 Muito legal! Só uma dúvida. Até pensei em perguntar no META, mas pelo o que voce tem feito, é bem-vindo fazer um par pergunta/resposta? Porque eu tenho um caso que não achei a resposta sobre um assunto especifico aqui no SOpt e tive que olhar documentacao e no SOen para conseguir fazer uma adptação para a minha solução. Nesse caso, seria bom eu postar um par pergunta/resposta?

Comment: ↑↑↑ não sei (ainda) se tem algo no META sobre o assunto...

Comment: @CmteCardeal Sim, responder a própria pergunta é [perfeitamente normal e dentro das regras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) - eu mesmo [já fiz isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/448955/112052)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Como foi dito que os métodos `doSomething` e `doSomethingElse` consomem toda a *stream*, então entendo que ambos precisam de todo o conteúdo dela.

Sendo assim, uma alternativa é - como dito na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/495637/112052) - ler todo o conteúdo do `InputStream` e guardá-lo em um array de bytes. Na outra resposta foi dada a solução com Java 9 (com [`transferTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo(java.io.OutputStream))), mas para versões anteriores você teria que ler o conteúdo manualmente, e escrevê-lo em um [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html):

```
void readStream(InputStream input) throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        baos.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    baos.flush();

    var result1 = doSomething(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));
    var result2 = doSomethingElse(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));
    // etc...
}
```

Com isso, eu obtenho um array de bytes (no caso acima, é o array retornado por `baos.toByteArray()`), que depois posso repassar para os métodos, encapsulado em um [`ByteArrayInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html). Assim, cada chamada é feita com uma *stream* nova, mas sempre contendo os mesmos dados.

> *O que daria para melhorar - caso você já "saiba" ou tenha uma noção do tamanho aproximado dos dados - é criar o `ByteArrayOutputStream` com o tamanho adequado (algo como `new ByteArrayOutputStream(tamanhoDosDados)`), assim você evita as realocações que são feitas durante as escritas: a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#%3Cinit%3E()) diz que o valor *default* da capacidade inicial é 32 (ou seja, apenas 32 bytes), então ao passar o tamanho mais próximo do real você minimiza a quantidade de vezes que o array interno é realocado.*

---

Vale lembrar que isso só se aplica se você tem memória suficiente para guardar todos os dados da *stream*.

Mas se não há memória suficiente, você precisa lê-la mais de uma vez e evitar que seja fechada (e não quer reabrí-la), daria para fazer uma "gambiarra": criar um *stream* que ao ser fechada, na verdade se reseta. Algo assim:

```
// solução ruim, veja considerações mais abaixo
public class ResetOnCloseInputStream extends InputStream {
    private InputStream in;
    public ResetOnCloseInputStream(InputStream in) {
        this.in = in;
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        return in.read();
    }

    // gambiarra: ao ser fechado, na verdade é resetado
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (in.markSupported()) {
            in.mark(0);
            in.reset();
        }
    }
}

...
ResetOnCloseInputStream resetIn = new ResetOnCloseInputStream(input);
var result1 = doSomething(resetIn);
var result2 = doSomethingElse(resetIn);
```

**Mas tem alguns problemas**: além de ser gambiarra, por estar (na minha opinião) deturpando o objetivo do método `close`, ferindo tanto a semântica deste quanto o [Princípio da Menor Surpresa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), nem toda *stream* pode suportar as operações de `mark` e `reset`. Então é um método pouco garantido que funcione, e só deixo registrado aqui como curiosidade.

---

Se não há memória suficiente para manter o array de bytes, outra opção é escrever o conteúdo do `input` em um arquivo temporário, e a cada chamada dos métodos que consomem os dados, criar uma nova *stream* que lê deste arquivo.

A partir do Java 7, pode-se usar o [pacote `java.nio`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/package-summary.html):

```
InputStream input = // input original

// salva os dados do input em um arquivo temporário
Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile("prefixo", "sufixo"); // prefixo e sufixo podem ser null (tanto faz, o arquivo é temporário e o Java cria um nome "único" mesmo...)
Files.copy(input, tempFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

// usa o arquivo temporário (cria um novo stream para cada método)
doSomething(Files.newInputStream(tempFile, StandardOpenOption.READ));
doSomethingElse(Files.newInputStream(tempFile, StandardOpenOption.READ));

// opcional: apaga o arquivo depois que terminar o processamento
Files.delete(tempFile);
```

Para Java < 7, use o `java.io` mesmo:

```
// copia os dados do input para um arquivo temporário
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("prefixo", "sufixo");
try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // trata erros, etc
}

// usa o arquivo temporário (cria um novo stream para cada método)
doSomething(new FileInputStream(tempFile));
doSomethingElse(new FileInputStream(tempFile));

// opcional: apaga o arquivo depois que terminar o processamento
tempFile.delete();
```

---

Por fim, se não há como manter os dados em memória e nem criar o arquivo temporário, o jeito é fazer o que você parece não querer: reabrir a *stream* e lê-la novamente.

Há também a opção de usar uma biblioteca externa, como já sugerido na outra resposta, mas tem alguns poréns:

---

#### Sobre o Apache Commons

Como foi dado a entender que os métodos que processam a *stream* lêem todos os dados desta, então `CloseShieldInputStream` - pelo menos nos testes que fiz - não parece ser uma boa solução:

```
InputStream input = // o input original

CloseShieldInputStream closeShieldForInput = new CloseShieldInputStream(input);
var result1 = doSomething(closeShieldForInput); // leu todos os dados do input
var result2 = doSomethingElse(closeShieldForInput); // não leu nada
```

Nos testes que fiz, criei os métodos `doSomething` e `doSomethingElse` de forma que eles leiam todos os dados da *stream* e a fechem no final (basicamente, "`while (read) etc` e `close`"). Com isso, somente `doSomething` leu os dados do `input`, mas `doSomethingElse` não conseguiu ler mais nada.

Isso acontece porque o que `CloseShieldInputStream` faz é somente evitar que o `InputStream` que ele encapsula seja fechado. Se olharmos o [código fonte](https://github.com/apache/commons-io/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/input/CloseShieldInputStream.java), veremos que na verdade o método `close` simplesmente seta o `InputStream` para um `ClosedInputStream` (e esta classe, por sua vez, [possui um método `read` que sempre retorna `-1`](https://github.com/apache/commons-io/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/input/ClosedInputStream.java) - ou seja, na prática é como uma *stream* "vazia", sem dados).

Por isso que após fechar um `CloseShieldInputStream`, o `input` original não é fechado, mas a tentativa de ler algo depois não traz nenhum dado. Então entendo que isso não serve para o seu caso. A [documentação](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/input/CloseShieldInputStream.html) diz o seguinte:

> *This class is typically used in cases where an input stream needs to be passed to a component that wants to explicitly close the stream **even if more input would still be available to other components**.*

Ou seja, ela é útil quando a *stream* é fechada antes de ter todos os dados lidos, mas você não quer que ela seja fechada, e deseja continuar a leitura de onde parou.
Por exemplo, criei um arquivo contendo o texto `abc` e fiz esse teste:

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("arquivo.txt"); // arquivo contendo "abc"

CloseShieldInputStream closeShieldForInput = new CloseShieldInputStream(input);
System.out.println(closeShieldForInput.read()); // 97 <- leu a letra "a"
System.out.println(closeShieldForInput.read()); // 98 <- leu a letra "b"

// não fecha o input original, mas seta o stream interno para um ClosedInputStream
closeShieldForInput.close();

System.out.println(closeShieldForInput.read()); // -1 <- a leitura está sendo feita no ClosedInputStream
System.out.println(closeShieldForInput.read()); // -1 <- a leitura está sendo feita no ClosedInputStream
// ao ler do input original, continua de onde parou (já que ele não foi fechado)
System.out.println(input.read()); // 99 <- leu a letra "c"
```

Repare que após o `CloseShieldInputStream` ser fechado, as chamadas a `read` retornam -1. Mas se eu ler diretamente do `input` original, ele continua aberto e os dados são lidos corretamente, do ponto de onde tinha parado.

Sendo assim, este não é uma boa solução para o caso de precisar consumir a *stream* inteira várias vezes. Você até poderia tentar resetar a *stream* antes de reusá-la, mas cai no problema já mencionado acima (nem todas as *streams* suportam `reset`), e além disso, depois do primeiro `reset` você teria que usar o `input` original em vez do `CloseShieldInputStream` (ou então criar outro).

---

Sobre o [`TeeInputStream`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/input/TeeInputStream.html), ele de fato funciona, em conjunto com [`PipedInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PipedInputStream.html) e [`PipedOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html):

```
InputStream input = // o input original

PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream();
TeeInputStream tee = new TeeInputStream(input, new PipedOutputStream(in));
var result1 = doSomething(tee);
var result2 = doSomethingElse(in);
```

Mas vale lembrar que internamente, está sendo feita uma cópia dos dados: ao ler do `TeeInputStream`, este envia os dados para o `PipedOutputStream`, que por sua vez envia os dados para `PipedInputStream`, que mantém uma cópia dos mesmos (ou seja, se houver limitação de memória, esta solução também não se aplicaria).

E tem outra limitação: se você quiser ler os dados novamente (pela terceira vez), não será possível:

```
InputStream input = // o input original

PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream();
TeeInputStream tee = new TeeInputStream(input, new PipedOutputStream(in));
var result1 = doSomething(tee);
var result2 = doSomethingElse(in);

var result3 = doAnotherThing(tee); // erro: tee está fechado
var result4 = doOneMoreThing(in); // erro: in está fechado
var result5 = doJustOneMoreThing(input); // erro: input está fechado
```

Pois tanto o `TeeInputStream` quanto o `PipedInputStream` (e o `input` original) estarão fechados.

Vale lembrar que isso não ocorre com as soluções com `ByteArrayInputStream` e com o arquivo temporário: com elas, podemos criar tantos quantos forem necessários. Então aquelas continuam sendo - na minha opinião - as melhores opções: se há memória suficiente para manter o array de bytes, `ByteArrayInputStream` é preferível, senão prefira criar o arquivo temporário.

Comment: Excelente como sempre hkotsubo, você e o Brenno trouxeram tudo o que tinha na pergunta original do SOEn e um pouco mais. Em alguns dias eu marco o aceite. Só vou deixar aberto para chamar atenção por um pouco mais de tempo e dar a chance para quem mais quiser responder.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Adicionei mais uma opção (que vi que não tem na pergunta original do SOen). Não é melhor que manter os dados em um array de bytes + `ByteArrayInputStream`, mas acho que é um bom "meio-termo" caso haja limitação de memória

Answer (score 5):

### Java 9

Nesta situação que você não quer fechar o input é possível utilizar o [InputStream.transferTo](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo(java.io.OutputStream)) e guardar em [ByteArrayOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html).

Será possível ler os dados e colocados em uma outra variável, criando um intermediário para os *bytes*.
É importante lembrar que para essa abordagem é necessário que a **memória seja suficiente** para conter todos os dados (e suas réplicas).

Um exemplo:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream foo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
input.transferTo(foo);
InputStream barOne = new ByteArrayInputStream(foo.toByteArray()); 
InputStream barTwo = new ByteArrayInputStream(foo.toByteArray());
InputStream barThree = new ByteArrayInputStream(foo.toByteArray()); 
// O quanto você tiver de memória disponível
```

### Apache Commons

É possível alcançar uma solução parecida também usando o [TeeInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/input/TeeInputStream.html) da [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/) em conjunto com o [PipedInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html) and [PipedOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html).

O [TeeInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/input/TeeInputStream.html) serve de proxy para a leitura do *InputStream* e o [PipedInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html) normalmente é utilizado em uma *thread* diferente para leitura e outra para gravação.

```
void readStream(InputStream input) throws Exception {
    // Cria o pipedInputStream para um input
    PipedInputStream pipInput = new PipedInputStream();
    // Cria um clone para o TeeInputStream
    TeeInputStream teeInput = new TeeInputStream(pipInput, new PipedOutputStream(input));

    // Agora você tem o teeInput e pipInput para manipular seu inputStream

}
```

Ainda como uma contra medida  você pode usar o [CloseShieldInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/input/CloseShieldInputStream.html) para evitar que os métodos na sequência fechem o *inputStream* original como no exemplo:

```
void readStream(InputStream input) throws Exception {
    CloseShieldInputStream closeShieldForInput = new CloseShieldInputStream(input);
    var result1 = doSomething(closeShieldForInput);
    var result2 = doSomethingElse(closeShieldForInput);
    // E no final o seu inputStream poderá ser lido
}
```