# TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.__format__ | Dicionarios e listas

Tags: python

Ola, estou fazendo meu código aqui até uma parte que acontece esse erro:

```
  File "path/main.py", line 45, in <module>
    print(f'{j[0]["id"]:<30} {j[1]:^30} {j[0]["GolsTotais"]:>30}')
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.__format__
```

Meu código:

```
jogadores = list()
gols = list()
listaAux = list()

dic = dict()

aux = 0
somaGols = 0

while True:
    dic['id'] = aux
    dic['nome'] = str(input('Nome do jogador > ')).strip().capitalize()
    dic['Qpartidas'] = int(input(f'Quantas partidas {dic["nome"]} jogou > '))
    
    for c in range(0, dic['Qpartidas']):
        
        golsAux = (int(input(f'Quantos gols na {c+1}º partida > ')))
        
        gols.append(golsAux)
        somaGols += golsAux
    
    dic['GolsTotais'] = somaGols
    listaAux.append(dic.copy())
    listaAux.append(gols[:])
    jogadores.append(listaAux[:])
    listaAux.clear()
    gols.clear()
    dic.clear()
    
    continuar = int(input('Deseja continuar? [1] Sim [2] Não > '))
    
    if continuar == 2:
        break

    aux += 1


print('-='*50)
cont = 0
print(jogadores)
while True:
    print(f'{"id":<30} {"gols":^30} {"total":>30}')
    for j in jogadores:
        print(j)
        print(f'{j[0]["id"]:<30} {j[1]:^30} {j[0]["GolsTotais"]:>30}')
    
    input()
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver a minha questão, o problema era apenas a formatação:

Antes:

```
print(f'{j[0]["id"]:<30} {j[1]:^30} {j[0]["GolsTotais"]:>30}')
```

Depois:

```
print(f'{str(j[0]["id"]):<15} {str(j[1]):^15} {str(j[0]["GolsTotais"]):>15}')
```

Não podemos fazer alinhamento em listas, transformando-as em strings conseguimos!

Comment: "*Não podemos fazer alinhamento em listas, transformando-as em strings conseguimos*" - Complementando, esse comportamento é explicado aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/448955/112052 - Mas na verdade eu sugiro rever esta estrutura, pois está bem confusa: vc tem uma lista onde cada elemento é outra lista, que por sua vez contém um dicionário e uma outra lista. Uma sugestão para simplificar seria cada dicionário que representa um jogador ter todas as informações nele (inclusive os gols): https://ideone.com/WfbgoI

Comment: Aaah, sim. Eu sei que está bem confusa ela, é que estou fazendo o curso de python e o professor pediu para mim fazer desta maneira como treino.